# Parallel processing in python on several Windows computers through ssh

Tags: python, ssh, parallel-processing

I used to do parallel processing in R across several Windows computers through SSH:

```
# Assume there are two computers, pc1 and pc2, both accessible by 
# user1 through SSH from the master computer, master_pc.
hosts <- list(list(host = "pc1", user = "user1"), list(host = "pc2", user = "user1"))
my_cl <- parallel::makeCluster(type   = 'PSOCK',
                               master = "master_pc",
                               spec   = hosts)
# Calls to functions from the parallel package that use the cluster my_cl
```

I know fork in Linux computers is a better approach but those computers have to run Windows and so sock is my only option.

I am going to do some parallel processing tasks in Python on these computers. Can I do something as simple as the approach above in Python?

I checked and [parallel-ssh](https://pypi.org/project/parallel-ssh/) seems to be what I need. However, the version at PyPI was [last updated at Nov 2018](https://pypi.org/project/parallel-ssh/#history). I am not sure if it is safe to write code using this package. I searched the Internet but most solutions I found are for Linux computers, or for single-machine parallel processing.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to setup cluster using `Dask`. I had used that in one of my Project and it worked absolutely awesome. You can do cluster setup using `SSH` as well or choose the one that suits your requirement. Please find the Procedure from  [Official Documentation](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/setup/ssh.html)

Hope it helps.